# localeCompare acts strangely when comparing two strings

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to write this code on console:

```
'B'.localeCompare('a')
```

I have been getting "1" from that, even though by ascii "a" is bigger so I should get -1.

I was trying to look for any consistency but with no success.

I would be glad to get a clear explanation how this method really works.

Comment: Look for sensitivity options here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alphabetically, both `B` and `b` come *after* `a`, so the following will yield positive:

```
'B'.localeCompare('a');
'b'.localeCompare('a');
```

A positive value means the calling object (the string `B`/`b`) comes after the argument (the string `a`) in sort order.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with ascii? is it just the order of the letters, when capital letters are "bigger"?

Comment: Correct. The order is something like `aAbBcCdD...` and so on. For instance, `'a'.localeCompare('A')` is -1 because `a` comes before `A` in sort order.

Comment: I tought about that but couldn't find any place had a clear record for that. Thanks!